# Hosting multiple laravel 5.5 projects on a single VPS with apache?

Tags: apache, laravel, digital-ocean, vhosts

I have a Digital Ocean VPS, what I want to do is to setup multiple applications but changing only the http://ip/:project.

I already have this on my apache .conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rovix/public
    <Directory /var/www/rovix/public/>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /var/www/rovix/public
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /aleman /var/www/aleman
    <Directory /var/www/aleman/public/>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /var/www/aleman/public
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

So far Alias /aleman is working because it lead me to the folders but when I enter to public is not working anymore. Any ideas of how can I achieve this? Thank you!

## Update

```
Alias /aleman /var/www/aleman/public
    DocumentRoot /var/www/aleman/public
    <Directory /var/www/aleman/public/>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /var/www/aleman/public
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I already change the configuration as you suggested.

But if I don't overwrite the DocumentRoot then I got redirected to the root /

And if I overwrite the DocumentRoot the urls are gotten mixed.

Is there another way to achieve separate urls for each project?

Comment: What does changing `http://ip/:project` mean? Do you mean you are using IP-based vhosts?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to change `Alias /aleman /var/www/aleman` to `Alias /aleman /var/www/aleman/public`. I've found that "clicking" into the `public` folder isn't very nice to the Laravel router.

I assume you know this, but for others' sake, remember to restart Apache after editing the file, or the changes won't take effect.

Comment: Not only is clicking 'public' not very nice but also a critical compromise to the security. Someone writing down https://something/aleman/.env -- will download the .env file in a beautiful plaintext format.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I agree, depending on Apache's configuration, the hidden files could be loaded.

Comment: I already change the configuration as you suggested:

Alias /aleman /var/www/aleman/public
        DocumentRoot /var/www/aleman/public
        <Directory /var/www/aleman/public/>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /var/www/aleman/public
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

But if I don't overwrite the DocumentRoot then I got redirected to the root /
And if I overwrite the DocumentRoot the urls are gotten mixed.
Is there another way to achieve separate urls for each project?